# How do I convert this list of tuples into a dictionary using a function and for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

```
studentdictionary = {}
tuplist = [("Charles",8,85),("Bea",9,95),("Coral",8,75)]
def students(studentlist):
    n = 0
    for t in tuplist:
        n+=1
        for name,age,grade in t:
            studentdictionary[n]["name"] = name
            studentdictionary[n]["age"] = age
            studentdictionary[n]["class grade"] = grade
    return studentdictionary
print(students(tuplist))
#goal output: {1:{"name": "Charles", "age": 8, "class grade": 85},2:{"name": "Bea", "age": 9, "class grade": 95},3:{"name": "Coral", "age": 8, "class grade": 75}}
```

I'm just a beginner and have looked all over the place to help. Please don't be brutal!

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 81, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 76, in students
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary-comprehension with `enumerate()`:

```
tuplist = [("Charles", 8, 85), ("Bea", 9, 95), ("Coral", 8, 75)]

studentdictionary = {
    i: {"name": name, "age": age, "grade": grade}
    for i, (name, age, grade) in enumerate(tuplist, 1)
}

print(studentdictionary)
```

Prints:

```
{1: {'name': 'Charles', 'age': 8, 'grade': 85}, 2: {'name': 'Bea', 'age': 9, 'grade': 95}, 3: {'name': 'Coral', 'age': 8, 'grade': 75}}
```